# How to run PHPUnit Test from another directory

Tags: phpunit

I have a very straightforward PHPUnit test in c:\kim\test\HelloTest.php on a Windows PC.  I can execute it from within the c:\kim\test directory with the command:

```
phpunit HelloTest
```

The problem is that I can't execute it from any other directory.

As far as I know I should be able to execute this from the c:\kim directory with:

```
phpunit test
```

Also, I would have thought the following syntax would work too:

```
phpunit c:\kim\test
```

But I don't get any response from the command.  Simply a blank line and then I am returned to the cursor.

I am trying to get unit tests working properly with Netbeans and I think I need to solve this problem first.  Perhaps it has something to do with paths?  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a `bootstrap.php` file that sets up your include path? Does `HelloTest.php` load any other PHP files? When I run PHPUnit for a single file, I give the filename and not the class name. Try adding `.php` to the end. The directory by itself should work.

Comment: Thanks David.  The HelloTest.php does a require_once for the file which it is testing (and obviously it finds it).  There is no bootstrap (however I also have the problem on a suite of bootstrapped Zend tests).  I see what you mean about using filename, not class name.  Works for me too, but does not solve the issue.  What do I need to have on my include path?

Comment: In my `bootstrap.php` files I add my source folder and the path to Zend Framework to the include path and initialize the Zend autoloader. Everything else is application-specific. Is it possible that when the current directory is `test` the require in your test can find the source file but not when in a different directory?

Comment: Hi David, I have setup a small php file to test (i.e. to take Zend out of the equation).  I tried extending the include_path to the test source file as you suggest, but no joy.  Also, tried using an absolute reference in the require() in teh test case, but no joy.  It's definitely finding the files it needs...  I'm going to setup phpunit on a new PC (with Zend Server CE) and see if the problems recurrs.  Thanks for your ideas...

Comment: You need the path to the class being tested--not the test itself. It should find the test file simply by naming it on the command line. However, that you put an absolute path in the test file's require line makes me think there's something else amiss, especially since you don't receive any error message.

Comment: Yep, used the class to the path being tested.  I see that wasn't too clear in my comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent quite a while trying to sort this out, per the comments above.  Also tried reinstalling PHPUnit.  In the end I ran up a new server, installed XAMPP, and all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If any help.
I am using makegood extension for eclipse which handle phpunit test execution with one click.
Maybe you can find similar extension for Netbeans or switch to eclipse

Comment: Thanks lenzai.  Since I only started using Netbeans today, I think I'll give it a few more days before I give up on it!

Comment: There seems to be nice integration of phpunit in Netbeans too : 
http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/phpunit.html

Comment: Thanks lenzai.  That's what started me down this path today.  I wanted to use the netbeans integration.  It partially works, but not fully.  For example, I can test the whole project from within netbeans, but can not create new test files...